# behaviorSubject next() not working angular 8

Tags: angular, observable, angular8, behaviorsubject, rxjs-observables

I have a `HeaderComponent` which displays the header in which I have a search bar, where a user when inputs something and presses enter I take the user to `SearchComponent`.

I want to implement the functionality that when a user is on search page (`SearchComponent`), the searchBar in header should not be visible while it should be visible on all other pages.

For this, I added variable `searchShow` in `HeaderComponent.ts` and by `ng-if` in `HeaderComponent.html`,
I show/hide the searchBar.

To change the value of `searchShow`, I implemented a `Header.service.ts`.

**header.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeaderService {
  showSearch = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  public showSearchObservable = this.showSearch.asObservable()
  constructor(){}
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderService } from './header.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  searchShow;
  constructor(
    private headerService: HeaderService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headerService.showSearchObservable.subscribe(
      value => {
        this.searchShow = value
        console.log(value) ##==> prints true first time when header is initialized but does not prints anything when search component is loaded
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderService } from 'src/app/shared/header/header.service.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(
    private headerService: HeaderService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.headerService.showSearch.value) ##==> prints true
    this.headerService.showSearch.next(false)
    console.log(this.headerService.showSearch.value) ##==> prints false, but this value is not emitted to header component
}
}
```

What am I missing? Please help. Thanks

Comment: I suspect you are somehow getting two different instances of `HeaderService`. Could you check how many times the constructor is being called? Are you attempting to provide it through an `NgModule`?

Comment: Usually you'd expose a different public observable using `asObservable` rather than directly subscribing to the `BehaviorSubject`. This would be similar to what is seen in the [documention](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case but I am not sure where I am instantiating the second instance of headerService.  As you can see, in the constructor of SearchComponent I am instantiating headerService, could this be the case?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I have added asObservable (update my question code as well) but same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In search.component.ts you reference

`import { HeaderService } from 'src/app/shared/header/header.service.js';`

Which is causing a second headerService instance. Taking `.js` suffix should fix this issue.

Comment: I changed it to a getter as you suggested, but the value still not propagates to the header component from the search component.

Comment: Something is weird in the imports, see in `search.component.ts` you reference `import { HeaderService } from 'src/app/shared/header/header.service.js';` which includes suffix `.js`, maybe take the suffix off?

Comment: Yes, removing the suffix worked, as now the value propagated to the header component. but now  I am receiving this error in the console.
` ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.`

Comment: Where is this error coming from? 
This error is related to template and change detection mechanizm. It isn't related to the subject. Maybe post another stackoverflow question for it or check this article: https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/

Comment: this is originating because I am changing the value of  searchShow in header component whenever I receive new value for showSearchObservable.